# How to run imdbpy2sql.py and import data from IMDb to postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, imdb, imdbpy

I'm startint a project on my own and I'm having some troubles with importing datas from *IMDb*. Already downloaded everything that's necessary but I'm kinda newbie in this python and command lines stuff, and it's pissing me off because I'm doing my homework (trying to learn how to do these things) but I can't reach it :(

So, is there anybody who could create a step-by-step of how to do it? I mean, something like:

You'll need to download this and run this commands on 'x'.

Create a database and then run 'x'.

It would be amazing for me and other people who don't know how to do this as well and I would truly appreciate A LOT, really!. Oh, I'm using Windows.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Hello, Rick. The problem is that I don't know how to proceed with the stuff I download (I mean the archives to import the whole data from IMDb) and wish someone who already did these things could help me on my way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!
For those who are having the same problem, here it goes:
Download the java movie database. It works witch postrgres or mysql. You'll have to download java runtime. After that open the readme in the directory you installed the java movie database, there are all the instructions, but I'll help you.
Follow the link off the *.list archives and download then. Move them into a new folder. After that, open JMDB (java movie database) and select the right folders of moviecollection, sound etc (they are in C:/programs...). In IMDb-import select the folder you created which contains the *.files. Well, this is the end. Run the JMDB and you'll have your DB populated.